# firebase-admin auth error while calling `getUser`, but work fine when calling verifyToken

Tags: node.js, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

While using `firebase-admin` on server-side,
I need to get user data from the firebase authentication.
But I found that if I use jwt token which firebase provided,
I couldn't get email or other providers' data from decoding token.
(pretty sure that I've added specific scopes properly.)

Then I turned to using firebase admin api to get user data from firebase's authentication.

The code look like this:

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

const auth = admin.auth()
auth.verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(decodedToken => decodedToken.user_id)
  .then(uid => {
    auth.getUser(user_id)
      .then((userRecord) => {
        console.log("Successfully fetched user data:", userRecord.json());
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error fetching user data:", error);
      });
  })
```

Then I got an error:

```
Error fetching user data: Error: error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
   at Error (native)
   at Sign.sign (crypto.js:283:26)
   at Object.sign (~/app/node_modules/jwa/index.js:55:45)
   at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (~/app/node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:23:24)
   at Object.module.exports [as sign] (~/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/sign.js:144:16)
   at CertCredential.createAuthJwt_ (~/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:190:20)
   at CertCredential.getAccessToken (~/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/credential.js:162:26)
   at SignedApiRequestHandler.sendRequest (~/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/api-request.js:110:32)
   at ~/app/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:381:50
   at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:129:7)
```

This might be a permission error,
according to this guess, I've found this might be related to this problem on stackoverflow:

[Firebase admin().auth().getUser(uid) Error: An internal error has occurred 'auth/internal-error'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639949/firebase-admin-auth-getuseruid-error-an-internal-error-has-occurred-auth)

But even I change the IAM of admin client to role: editor,
this error still happened.
Wondering what's going on, 
and why admin can verify token but can be granted to read user data (even I give the service account root access to my project).

Any suggestion would be helpful for me.

Comment: The code sample you provided has a bunch of syntax and code errors which make it hard for me to repro. For example, you don't ever call initializeApp(). You also use undefined `idtoken` and `user_id` variables. Finally, your first `console.log()` line is missing a closing parenthesis. Can you please put together a full repro to help us debug this? See my answer below for how to most easily resolve your issue. If that doesn't work, please try upgrading to the latest version of the SDK (4.0.6) which has some new error handling. Also, it would be great to know where you got the invalid key file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best bet as to what is going wrong is that the private key within the service account key file you are using is invalid. To get a valid service account key file, follow the instructions in [Add Firebase to your app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app). There is a nice UI which you can use to generate a new JSON file which should have all the proper permissions for your project. You can use it to initialize your SDK like this:

```
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
```