# Firebase admin().auth().getUser(uid) internal error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

`firebaseAdmin.auth().getUser(uid)` causes the following error:

```
Error: An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{}"
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/home/nowuser/src/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (/home/nowuser/src/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:104:23)
    at Function.FirebaseAuthError.fromServerError (/home/nowuser/src/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:128:16)
    at /home/nowuser/src/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:364:45
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:169:7)
```

This error occurs **only** when I deploy to production on Zeit Now; when I run my app in production mode on localhost, I do not get this error. I ensured that the app runs the same locally and on production by putting it in a Docker container.

How can I fix this error?

---

Note:

I am aware that this question has already been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40639949/firebase-admin-auth-getuseruid-error-an-internal-error-has-occurred-auth), but the accepted answer (change the permissions of the service account) did not work for me. Also, that question does not show the full error received, so I'm not convinced it's exactly the same error.

---

Update: Below is the code that pertains to this question. Basically, the server starts an express server which uses the POST authWithIdToken route to set a cookie containing the user's firebase auth idToken. It uses authenticationMiddleware to check for a cookie with idToken, and if it exists, then to decode the token and fetch the user's data. The errors occur at the getUser(uid) step. The `getFirebaseAdminInitConfig` function gets the init config, which is provided using ENV variables.

```
# server.js - excerpt showing authentication middleware and authWithIdTokenRoute
const server = express()
# ...
allowParsingPostBody(server)
server.use(cookieParser())
server.use('*', authenticationMiddleware)
server.post('/authWithIdToken', authWithIdTokenRoute)
# ...



# authenticationMiddleware.js
const { FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE } = require('../universal/constants')
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin')
const winston = require('winston')
const getFirebaseAdminInitConfig = require('./getFirebaseAdminInitConfig')

winston.info(
  'Initializing Firebase Admin with Config:',
  getFirebaseAdminInitConfig()
)

firebaseAdmin.initializeApp(getFirebaseAdminInitConfig())

async function decodeToken (firebaseIdToken) {
  try {
    const decodedToken = await firebaseAdmin.auth().verifyIdToken(firebaseIdToken)
    return decodedToken
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code !== 'auth/internal-error') throw error
    winston.warn(
      'firebase admin auth verifyIdToken auth/internal-error:',
      {
        firebaseIdToken,
        error
      }
    )
  }
}

const getFullUrl = (req) => (
  req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl
)

const getRedirectUrl = (req) => (
  `/redirect?url=${encodeURIComponent(getFullUrl(req))}`
)

async function getUserData (uid) {
  try {
    const userData = await firebaseAdmin.auth().getUser(uid)
    return userData
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.code !== 'auth/internal-error') throw error
    winston.warn(
      'firebase admin auth getUser auth/internal-error:',
      {
        uid,
        error
      }
    )
  }
}

async function authenticationMiddleware (req, res, next) {
  const { firebaseIdToken } = req.cookies

  if (firebaseIdToken) {
    try {
      req.currentUserServerData = await getUserData(
        (await decodeToken(firebaseIdToken))
        .uid
      )
    } catch (error) {
      res.clearCookie(FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE)

      // if the cookie id token has expired, redirect the user to
      // /redirect?url={requestedUrl} - the client will try to set
      // a new cookie and then will redirect to requestedUrl
      if (error.code === 'auth/argument-error') {
        return res.redirect(getRedirectUrl(req))
      } else {
        winston.warn('Unexpected error occurred while processing firebase idToken:', error)
      }
    }
  }

  next()
}

authenticationMiddleware.authWithIdTokenRoute = async function ({body: { idToken }}, res) {
  try {
    await decodeToken(idToken)
    const expireDate = (new Date())
    expireDate.setYear((new Date()).getFullYear() + 1)
    res.cookie(FIREBASE_ID_TOKEN_COOKIE, idToken, { expires: expireDate })
    return res.send()
  } catch (error) {
    winston.warn('authWithIdTokenRoute unexpected error', {
      idToken,
      error
    })

    if (error.code === 'auth/argument-error') {
      return res
      .status(400)
      .send({
        error: new Error('Could not decode token')
      })
    } else {
      return res.status(500).send()
    }
  }
}

module.exports = authenticationMiddleware



# getFirebaseAdminInitConfig.js
const firebaseAdmin = require('firebase-admin')

// ENV variables are set in .env file and loaded by dotenv.
// See for more info: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv
const getFirebaseCredentials = () => {
  const {
    FIREBASE_TYPE: type,
    FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID: projectId,
    FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY_ID: privateKeyId,
    FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY: privateKey,
    FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL: clientEmail,
    FIREBASE_CLIENT_ID: clientId,
    FIREBASE_AUTH_URI: authUri,
    FIREBASE_TOKEN_URI: tokenUri,
    FIREBASE_AUTH_PROVIDER_CERT_URL: authProviderX509CertUrl,
    FIREBASE_CLIENT_CERT_URL: clientX509CertUrl
  } = process.env

  return {
    type,
    projectId,
    privateKeyId,
    privateKey,
    clientEmail,
    clientId,
    authUri,
    tokenUri,
    authProviderX509CertUrl,
    clientX509CertUrl
  }
}

const getDatabaseUrl = () => {
  const { projectId } = getFirebaseCredentials()
  return `https://${projectId}.firebaseio.com`
}

module.exports = () => ({
  credential: firebaseAdmin.credential.cert(getFirebaseCredentials()),
  databaseURL: getDatabaseUrl()
})
```

And here are the logs from my production app, deployed with Zeit Now:

```
08/03 08:07 AM (4m)
REQ "GET /ka/login HTTP/2.0" 69.243.47.183 -  "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
08/03 08:07 AM (4m)
RES "GET /ka/login HTTP/2.0" 200 3285
08/03 08:07 AM (4m)
REQ "GET /_next/01caf4c5-c7ab-4006-9f22-0e27366468c1/page/login HTTP/2.0" 69.243.47.183 -  "https://georgian-chant-site-dzhuccwhhp.now.sh/ka/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
08/03 08:07 AM (4m)
RES "GET /_next/01caf4c5-c7ab-4006-9f22-0e27366468c1/page/login HTTP/2.0" 200 37351
08/03 08:08 AM (4m)
REQ "GET /_next/01caf4c5-c7ab-4006-9f22-0e27366468c1/page/admin HTTP/2.0" 69.243.47.183 -  "https://georgian-chant-site-dzhuccwhhp.now.sh/ka/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
08/03 08:08 AM (4m)
RES "GET /_next/01caf4c5-c7ab-4006-9f22-0e27366468c1/page/admin HTTP/2.0" 200 675
08/03 08:08 AM (4m)
REQ "POST /authWithIdToken HTTP/2.0" 69.243.47.183 -  "https://georgian-chant-site-dzhuccwhhp.now.sh/ka/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
08/03 08:08 AM (3m)
debug: Successful outgoing request. Request: { port: null,
  path: '/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com',
  host: 'www.googleapis.com',
  protocol: 'https:',
  auth: null,
  hostname: 'www.googleapis.com',
  hash: null,
  search: null,
  query: null,
  pathname: '/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com',
  href: 'https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com',
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { host: 'www.googleapis.com' },
  body: '' } Response:  statusCode=200, expires=Thu, 03 Aug 2017 17:45:27 GMT, date=Thu, 03 Aug 2017 10:45:53 GMT, vary=X-Origin, Origin,Accept-Encoding, content-type=application/json; charset=UTF-8, x-content-type-options=nosniff, x-frame-options=SAMEORIGIN, x-xss-protection=1; mode=block, server=GSE, cache-control=public, max-age=25174, must-revalidate, no-transform, age=4937, alt-svc=quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,36,35", accept-ranges=none, connection=close, , httpVersion=1.1, url=, method=null, body={
 "{{hash retracted}}": "{{certificate retracted}}",
 "{{hash retracted}}": "{{certificate retracted}}",
 "{{hash retracted}}": "{{certificate retracted}}",
 "{{hash retracted}}": "{{certificate retracted}}""
}
08/03 08:08 AM (3m)
RES "POST /authWithIdToken HTTP/2.0" 200 897
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
REQ "GET /ka/admin HTTP/2.0" 69.243.47.183 -  "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
warn: firebase admin auth getUser auth/internal-error: uid={{uid retracted}}, code=auth/internal-error, message=An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{}"
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
RES "GET /ka/admin HTTP/2.0" 302 184
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
REQ "GET /ka/login HTTP/2.0" 69.243.47.183 -  "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
warn: firebase admin auth getUser auth/internal-error: uid={{uid retracted}}, code=auth/internal-error, message=An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{}"
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
RES "GET /ka/login HTTP/2.0" 200 3285
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
REQ "POST /authWithIdToken HTTP/2.0" 69.243.47.183 -  "https://georgian-chant-site-dzhuccwhhp.now.sh/ka/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
RES "POST /authWithIdToken HTTP/2.0" 200 897
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
warn: firebase admin auth getUser auth/internal-error: uid={{uid retracted}}, code=auth/internal-error, message=An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{}"
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
REQ "POST /authWithIdToken HTTP/2.0" 69.243.47.183 -  "https://georgian-chant-site-dzhuccwhhp.now.sh/ka/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
warn: firebase admin auth getUser auth/internal-error: uid={{uid retracted}}, code=auth/internal-error, message=An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{}"
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
RES "POST /authWithIdToken HTTP/2.0" 200 894
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
REQ "POST /authWithIdToken HTTP/2.0" 69.243.47.183 -  "https://georgian-chant-site-dzhuccwhhp.now.sh/ka/login" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36"
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
RES "POST /authWithIdToken HTTP/2.0" 200 894
08/03 08:08 AM (2m)
warn: firebase admin auth getUser auth/internal-error: uid={{uid retracted}}, code=auth/internal-error, message=An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{}"
```

---

Update 8/15/2017: Here's the stacktrace for the error above when run with firebaseAdmin v5.2.0 (above stacktrace was for an earlier version of firebaseAdmin).

```
firebase admin auth getUser auth/internal-error: uid=RBwhJQy3ImStgNYvZICTT8M48Co1, code=auth/internal-error, message=An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{}", stacktrace=Error: An internal error has occurred. Raw server response: "{}"
    at FirebaseAuthError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (/myapp/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:39:28)
    at new FirebaseAuthError (/myapp/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:104:23)
    at Function.FirebaseAuthError.fromServerError (/myapp/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/utils/error.js:128:16)
    at /myapp/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js:399:45
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: Perhaps your production server is behind a proxy or a firewall that prevents the SDK from connecting to the ID toolkit servers. Can you use a module like [global-request-logger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/global-request-logger) to log HTTP interactions with the backend server, and see what you get?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Thanks for the tip on global-request-logger. I added that, and the log output shows only a single successful outgoing request when the app starts up, almost certainly to initialize the firebase admin app. After that, there are no more requests logged at all (neither successful nor errored) - only the "internal error has occurred" errors I described in this question.

Comment: Could you share the logs you have? I would expect to see 2 outgoing requests: one to get an OAuth2 token, and another to the ID toolkit server. Also show us some of your code (especially how you initialize the admin app).

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Added the initialization code, the routing code, and the logs. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: The HTTP request captured in the log is from the `verifyIdToken()` call (to fetch public key certificates). It's puzzling why no other requests are logged. Since this is happening only in one environment, is it possible that environment is blocking some of the outgoing HTTP traffic? Also please confirm the version of the Firebase SDK you're using, and we can try to go through the minified JS files to figure out where your exception (logged above) originates from.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Sorry for the slow response. I'm deploying to Zeit Now, but I'm not sure why they would block outgoing HTTP traffic. Any ideas on how to find out? I just updated my firebase libraries to the latest versions, `firebase v4.2.0` and `firebase-admin v5.2.0`, and the problem is still occurring. I searched for the error in the minified JS files, but because they're minified it's hard to say what's causing the problem.

Comment: Are the line numbers in the stacktrace same when running against v5.2.0? And why do you have firebase module in the project? That should only be used in client-side (browser) environments.

Comment: I have the firebase module in the project because the project is universal (runs both on the server and on the client). I'm pretty sure this is not the cause of the bug, as the bug only occurs when the application is deployed. About the stacktrace, are you suggesting that I compare the line numbers for the error between different firebase-admin versions?

Comment: I added the stacktrace for the error when run with firebase-admin v5.2.0. The error has slightly different line numbers but otherwise is the same.

Comment: Can you add `console.log(response);` as line 386 in `node_modules/firebase_admin/lib/auth/auth-api-request.js`, run your test and see if you get a new log output?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka I'm only getting this error when I deploy to Zeit Now, but I guess I could change my Docker build so that it adds the `console.log(response)` line into `auth-api-request.js` after installing node modules. Does that sound like a good idea?

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Out of frustration and not wanting to spend any more time on this bug, I tried deploying to Heroku instead of Zeit Now... and it worked! So I'm going to use Heroku instead of Zeit. I assume that therefore the problem is with Zeit, but short of adding console.logs to my docker build (which I don't really feel like doing), I'm not sure of how I would continue debugging. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It was caused by extra quotes in the parameters passed to firebase-admin's `initializeApp(...)`, similar to this thread: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/137

Check whether the parameters you pass to `initializeApp(...)` are correct.